# Use javacript to change a div width and move an inner div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need to move a right-aligned div from one position to another using a button-powered javascript.

So the page is rendered and the outer div is a set width using `position:relative;width:250px;`. The inside div uses `position:absolute;right:0px;` to place it to the far right of the outer div.

I assumed that if my javascript set the width of the outer div it would change the outer div width and the inner div would move relatively to that. But it doesn't move (even though getting the width value of the outer div confirms that the new value was set).

Does this means that you cannot change div widths once the page has been rendered? As they can be changed if the browser window width changes I presumed this would be possible.

```
<div id="test" style="display:inline-block;position:relative;width:250px;">
    <div style="display:inline-block;">
        Some text
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;position:absolute;right:0px;">
        Some more text
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="resizeouter(500);">
    Move Right
</button>

<script>
function resizeouter(newsize){
    document.getElementById('test').width=newsize+"px";
    //alert(document.getElementById('test').width);
}
</script>
```

I've tried with and without the +"px".

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markdibley/weu5osay/7/)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add .style.width

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_width.asp

```js
function resizeouter(elementID, newsize){
  let div = document.getElementById(elementID); // current element
  let currentWidth = div.offsetWidth; // current width of your element
  let finalWidth = currentWidth + newsize; // addition of current width + newsize

  div.style.width=finalWidth+"px"; // set the new width for this element 
  //alert(document.getElementById('test').width);
    
  // debug infos
  console.log(currentWidth + ' + ' + newsize + ' = ' + finalWidth);
}
```

```html
<div id="test" style="display:inline-block;position:relative;width:250px;">
    <div style="display:inline-block;">
        Some text
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;position:absolute;right:0px;">
        Some more text
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="resizeouter('test', 500);">
    Move Right
</button>
```

Comment: That totally works and makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Plz validate my answer

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is `style.width`:

```
document.getElementById('test').style.width= newsize+"px";
```

Comment: I had looked at it for so long I didn't notice it was missing. Thank you!